# How to block form submissions if the message field contains certain words (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring, contains

I want to prevent the contact form from submission if the message field contains certain words. I used *one*, *two* and *three* as an example:

```
//Prevent the form from submission if it contains one, two, or three
$needle = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
if (stripos($message, $needle) !== false) {
    echo "$message contains $needle";
}
```

This did not work for me. However, I tested this with one word only and it worked:

```
if (stripos($message, 'one') !== false) {
    echo 'invalid message format';
}
```

How can I check on multiple words in a message in PHP if the above array is not working?

Comment: The arguments to `stripos()` have to be strings. `$needle` is an array, not a string.

Comment: You want to block it if it contains *all* the words, or *any* of the words?

Comment: I want to block it if it contains any of the words

Comment: @Abe please check my answer and give me your feedback.

Comment: @Nikita, thanks. I checked both of your answers, and the second works well and shows what exactly goes wrong. I think Barmar has submitted a great solution, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use for loop.

```
$needle_arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$included = [];

foreach($needle_arr as $needle)
  if (stripos($message, $needle) !== false) {
      $included []= $needle;
  }

if(count($included) > 0)
  echo "$message contains ".implode(", ", $included);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array.

```
$word_found = false;
foreach ($needles as $word) {
    if (stripos($message, $word) !== false) {
        $word_found = $word;
        break;
    }
}
if ($word_found) {
    echo "$message contains $word_found";
}
```